# how to connect a kubernetes pod to the outside world without a forwarding rule (google container engine)

Tags: firewall, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using Google's Container Engine service, and got a pod running a server listening on port 3000. I set up the service to connect port 80 to that pod's port 3000. I am able to curl the service using its local and public ip from within the node, but not from outside. I set up a firewall rule to allow port 80 and send it to the node, but I keep getting 'connection refused' from outside the network. I'm trying to do this without a forwarding rule, since there's only one pod and it looked like forwarding rules cost money and do load balancing. I think the firewall rule works, because when I add the `createExternalLoadBalancer: true` to the service's spec, the external IP created by the forwarding rule works as expected. Do I need to do something else? Set up a route or something?

controller.yaml

```
kind: ReplicationController
apiVersion: v1beta3
metadata:
    name: app-frontend
    labels:
        name: app-frontend
        app: app
        role: frontend
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        name: app-frontend
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                name: app-frontend
                app: app
                role: frontend
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: node-frontend
                  image: gcr.io/project_id/app-frontend
                  ports:
                    - name: app-frontend-port
                      containerPort: 3000
                      targetPort: 3000
                      protocol: TCP
```

service.yaml

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1beta3
metadata:
  name: app-frontend-service
  labels:
    name: app-frontend-service
    app: app
    role: frontend
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: app-frontend-port
      protocol: TCP
  publicIPs:
   - 123.45.67.89
  selector:
    name: app-frontend
```

---

**Edit (additional details):**
Creating this service adds these additional rules, found when I run `iptables -L -t nat`

```
Chain KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             10.247.247.206       /* default/app-frontend-service: */ tcp dpt:http redir ports 56859
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             89.67.45.123.bc.googleusercontent.com  /* default/app-frontend-service: */ tcp dpt:http redir ports 56859
Chain KUBE-PORTALS-HOST (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             10.247.247.206       /* default/app-frontend-service: */ tcp dpt:http to:10.241.69.28:56859
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             89.67.45.123.bc.googleusercontent.com  /* default/app-frontend-service: */ tcp dpt:http to:10.241.69.28:56859
```

I don't fully understand iptables, so I'm not sure how the destination port matches my service. I found that the DNS for `89.67.45.123.bc.googleusercontent.com` resolves to `123.45.67.89`.

kubectl get services shows the IP address and port I specified:

```
NAME                             IP(S)               PORT(S)
app-frontend-service             10.247.243.151      80/TCP
                                 123.45.67.89
```

Nothing recent from external IPs is showing up in  /var/log/kube-proxy.log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: Use the Internal IP of your node as the public IP in your service definition.

---

If you enable verbose logging on the kube-proxy you will see that it appears to be creating the appropriate IP tables rule:

```
I0602 04:07:32.046823   24360 roundrobin.go:98] LoadBalancerRR service "default/app-frontend-service:" did not exist, created
I0602 04:07:32.047153   24360 iptables.go:186] running iptables -A [KUBE-PORTALS-HOST -t nat -m comment --comment default/app-frontend-service: -p tcp -m tcp -d 10.119.244.130/32 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.240.121.42:36970]
I0602 04:07:32.048446   24360 proxier.go:606] Opened iptables from-host portal for service "default/app-frontend-service:" on TCP 10.119.244.130:80
I0602 04:07:32.049525   24360 iptables.go:186] running iptables -C [KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER -t nat -m comment --comment default/app-frontend-service: -p tcp -m tcp -d 23.251.156.36/32 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 36970]
I0602 04:07:32.050872   24360 iptables.go:186] running iptables -A [KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER -t nat -m comment --comment default/app-frontend-service: -p tcp -m tcp -d 23.251.156.36/32 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 36970]
I0602 04:07:32.052247   24360 proxier.go:595] Opened iptables from-containers portal for service "default/app-frontend-service:" on TCP 23.251.156.36:80
I0602 04:07:32.053222   24360 iptables.go:186] running iptables -C [KUBE-PORTALS-HOST -t nat -m comment --comment default/app-frontend-service: -p tcp -m tcp -d 23.251.156.36/32 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.240.121.42:36970]
I0602 04:07:32.054491   24360 iptables.go:186] running iptables -A [KUBE-PORTALS-HOST -t nat -m comment --comment default/app-frontend-service: -p tcp -m tcp -d 23.251.156.36/32 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.240.121.42:36970]
I0602 04:07:32.055848   24360 proxier.go:606] Opened iptables from-host portal for service "default/app-frontend-service:" on TCP 23.251.156.36:80
```

Listing the iptables entries using `-L -t` shows the public IP turned into the reverse DNS name like you saw:

```
Chain KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             10.119.240.2         /* default/kubernetes: */ tcp dpt:https redir ports 50353
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             10.119.240.1         /* default/kubernetes-ro: */ tcp dpt:http redir ports 54605
REDIRECT   udp  --  anywhere             10.119.240.10        /* default/kube-dns:dns */ udp dpt:domain redir ports 37723
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             10.119.240.10        /* default/kube-dns:dns-tcp */ tcp dpt:domain redir ports 50126
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             10.119.244.130       /* default/app-frontend-service: */ tcp dpt:http redir ports 36970
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             36.156.251.23.bc.googleusercontent.com  /* default/app-frontend-service: */ tcp dpt:http redir ports 36970
```

But adding the `-n` option shows the IP address (by default, `-L` does a reverse lookup on the ip address, which is why you see the DNS name):

```
Chain KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.119.240.2         /* default/kubernetes: */ tcp dpt:443 redir ports 50353
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.119.240.1         /* default/kubernetes-ro: */ tcp dpt:80 redir ports 54605
REDIRECT   udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.119.240.10        /* default/kube-dns:dns */ udp dpt:53 redir ports 37723
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.119.240.10        /* default/kube-dns:dns-tcp */ tcp dpt:53 redir ports 50126
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.119.244.130       /* default/app-frontend-service: */ tcp dpt:80 redir ports 36970
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            23.251.156.36        /* default/app-frontend-service: */ tcp dpt:80 redir ports 36970
```

At this point, you can access the service from within the cluster using both the internal and external IPs:

```
$ curl 10.119.244.130:80
app-frontend-5pl5s
$ curl 23.251.156.36:80
app-frontend-5pl5s
```

Without adding a firewall rule, attempting to connect to the public ip remotely times out. If you add a firewall rule then you will reliably get connection refused:

```
$ curl 23.251.156.36
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 23.251.156.36 port 80: Connection refused
```

If you enable some iptables logging:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER -m tcp -p tcp --dport 
80 -j LOG --log-prefix "WTF: "
```

And then grep the output of `dmesg` for `WTF` it's clear that the packets are arriving on the 10. IP address of the VM rather than the ephemeral external IP address that had been set as the public IP on the service.

It turns out that the problem is that GCE has two types of external IPs: ForwardingRules (which forward with the DSTIP intact) and 1-to-1 NAT (which actually rewrites the DSTIP to the internal IP). The external IP of the VM is the later type so when the node receives the packets the IP tables rule doesn't match.

The fix is actually pretty simple (but non-intuitive): Use the Internal IP of your node as the public IP in your service definition. After updating your service.yaml file to set publicIPs to the Internal IP  (e.g. `10.240.121.42`) you will be able to hit your application from outside of the GCE network.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working with the ip returned from `ifconfig` on the node. I wasn't sure how to enable verbose logging, or how else to get it.
Is this applicable to multi-node scenarios? If all the nodes' IPs were in the list, would it send it to whichever one had a container listening on that port? What would it do if two containers on two different nodes were listening on that port?

Comment: To enable verbose logging, edit `/etc/default/kube-proxy` and change `--v=2` to `--v=4`. Then run `sudo service kube-proxy restart`. The log file is written to `/var/log/kube-proxy.log`.

Comment: This is applicable to multi-node scenarios in the way that Alex described below -- you can add multiple publicIPs entries to your service and send requests to all of the nodes in your cluster (e.g. using DNS round robin). The kube-proxy on each node intercepts the requests and redirects them to the appropriate pods running in the cluster.

Comment: You will need to use different ports or different publicIPs for different externally exposed services (although pods can reuse the same port numbers inside the cluster because each pod gets a distinct IP). This is the advantage of using the GCE external load balancer -- since each service gets a different IP, you can use the same port (e.g. port 80 or 443) on all of your services.

Comment: @RobertBailey it does not seem to work like this anymore.If I set the internal ip as external on the service definition I cant access my app from nowhere except inside my cluster. Brand new GCE cluster running Kubernetes 1.1.7 btw.  Shame LoadBalancing cost more than the vm itself, it fucks my tests.

Comment: I can not repro this at head.  I set a Service with an LB and an externalIP of the VM's intra-GCE IP and it works.  Maybe you can send me your YAML?  You can email me if you don't want to post it here.

Comment: It looks like this answer does not apply anymore? Setting the internal ip of the node as the loadbalancerIp nor the externalIP seems to work for me

Answer (score 0):

If you add the node's external IP address to the service's `publicIPs` field, you should then be able to access it at the node's IP address. If your cluster has multiple nodes, you can put more than one of their IP addresses into the field  if you'd like to enable accessing the pod on any of them.

In an upcoming release there will be a simpler built-in option for setting up an external service without a load balancer. If you're curious or reading this sometime in the future, check out the updated "External Services" section of [this doc](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/pull/8655) to see how you'll be able to use use `NodePort` to accomplish the same thing much more easily.

Comment: I think I already followed the steps you mentioned. As you can see in my service.yaml, the service has a `publicIPs` field, which is set to the external ip of the node.

Comment: The firewall rule for port 80 and adding the node's external IP to the service's `publicIPs` field should be all that's needed to make it work. Once you've double checked that the IP in the service is the node's IP and that it's the same IP as the one you're testing against, the next place to look is to run `sudo iptables -L -t nat` on the node to see if there's an iptables rule referring to the IP address. Assuming there is, check /var/log/kube-proxy.log for any details on why requests to that service aren't being routed.

Comment: Confirmed that node's listed external IP matches that in service spec. I didn't see the listed IP in the iptables, but I did see it backwards as a prefix for the destination domain. I've updated my question with some additional details

Comment: To test the NodePort feature you are talking about, can I upgrade the cluster to use the latest version? Or do I need to start a new cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @Robert Bailey is absolutely correct. publicIPs has been deprecated in kubernetes 1.5.1, you can use externalIPs instead.

- get the internal ip of the node, `kubectl describe node | grep Address`
  `Addresses:     10.119.244.130,101.192.150.200,gke-...`
- or you can run the `ifconfig eth0` inside the node terminal to get the internal ip
- set the ip in service.yaml

  `spec:
    type: NodePort
    externalIPs:
      - 10.119.244.130`
- can curl with resolve to test
  `curl --resolve 'example.com:443:23.251.156.36' https://example.com -k`

Comment: This only works if you're not going to scale your pods (they might endup in a different externalIp). I would think that it would work also in case of reconstruction (pod dying and being recreated, as I would think it could be created somewhere else).